How can I differentiate between null value and empty string in query result?
I ran the following sql statement in SQL Workbench/J for redshift:
select null, '     ', len('     ')
This is what it returned. How can I differentiate between the null value and the empty string? In both, it shows as an empty string. I added the len just to make sure redshift wasn't truncating it.


Your workbench can be configured to display NULL with a string, like "NULL".  See: https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/options.html
